# JAVA - XML and JSON issue: Array management<

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml

I am programming Java after long time and i am just new to Json.
I found a strange issue but not sure if I am not understanding it correctly.

This is part of the XML file i am reading:

> ```
> <Events>
>       <event comment="topota1" file="test1.mp4" id="0" time="1000"/>
>       <event comment="topota2" file="test2.mp4" id="1" time="2000"/>
>       <event comment="topota3" file="test3.mp4" id="2" time="3000"/>
>       <event comment="topota4" file="test4.mp4" id="3" time="4000"/>
> </Events>
> ```

I did a Json structure to manage some events information:

> ```
> package miCMS;
> {***}
> import org.json.JSONArray;
> import org.json.JSONObject;
> {***}
> JSONObject Event = new JSONObject();
> JSONArray EventArr = new JSONArray();
> {***}
> public class miPlayer{
> {***}
>
> public void addEvent(int Id, int Time, String File, String Comment) {
>       try {
>           Event.put("Id", Id);
>           Event.put("Time", Time);
>           Event.put("File", File);
>           Event.put("Comment", Comment);
>           EventArr.put(Event);
>       }catch ( Exception e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
> }
> ```

In another Java file I am reading the XML file and asigning to my Json Array:

> ```
> package miCMS;
> {***}
> public class miXMLParser{
>
>   public static miCMS.miPlayer ReadFromXML(String Path){
>        try {
>
>           DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
>           parser.parse(Path);
>           Document doc = parser.getDocument();
>
> ///////////////////////////////////EVENTOS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>           NodeList childNodesEvent = doc.getElementsByTagName("event"); 
>
>           for (int x = 0; x < childNodesEvent.getLength(); x++ ) {
>               Node NodeEvent = childNodesEvent.item(x);
>
>               player.addEvent(x, 1000, "", "");
>
>               NamedNodeMap attrsEvent = NodeEvent.getAttributes();
>               for (int y = 0; y < attrsEvent.getLength(); y++ ) {
>                   Node attrEvent = attrsEvent.item(y);
>                   String AttribName = attrEvent.getNodeName();
>
>                   switch (AttribName) {
>                       case "id":  
>                           player.EventArr.getJSONObject(x).put("Id",Integer.parseInt(attrEvent.getNodeValue()));
>                           System.out.println(">X:" + x + " // Id:" + player.EventArr.getJSONObject(x).getInt("Id"));
>                           break;
>                       case "time":  
>                           player.EventArr.getJSONObject(x).put("Time",Integer.parseInt(attrEvent.getNodeValue()));
>                           break;
>                       case "file":  
>                           player.EventArr.getJSONObject(x).put("File",attrEvent.getNodeValue());
>                           break;
>                       case "comment":  
>                           player.EventArr.getJSONObject(x).put("Comment",attrEvent.getNodeValue());
>                           break;
>                   }           
>               }
>           }
>
>           System.out.println("DESPUES DEL FOR");
>           System.out.println(">>X:0" + " // Id:" + player.EventArr.getJSONObject(0).getInt("Id"));
>           System.out.println(">>X:1" + " // Id:" + player.EventArr.getJSONObject(1).getInt("Id"));
>           System.out.println(">>X:2" + " // Id:" + player.EventArr.getJSONObject(2).getInt("Id"));
>           System.out.println(">>X:3" + " // Id:" + player.EventArr.getJSONObject(3).getInt("Id"));
>
>       }catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>
>       return player;
>   }
> ```

for some reason, all the elements in my JSON array is storing the information coming form the last element in my XML file. 
I forced some printlines to see what is happening but is strange:

```
>X:0 // Id:0
>X:1 // Id:1
>X:2 // Id:2
>X:3 // Id:3
DESPUES DEL FOR
>>X:0 // Id:3
>>X:1 // Id:3
>>X:2 // Id:3
>>X:3 // Id:3
```

My question is: Why the info is being stored ok when inside the For loop but not when outside the For loop??

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSONObject::put` overrides keys, therefore, as your `JSONObject Event` is a class field, everytime you call `miPlayer::addEvent` it stores the very same `Event` object in a new cell of `EventArr`, updating all the other cells (because each cell contains a pointer to your `Event` object). To fix this, simply use a local variable :

```
package miCMS;
{***}
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
{***}
JSONArray eventArr = new JSONArray();
{***}
public class MiPlayer{
{***}

public void addEvent(int id, int time, String file, String comment) {
    try {
        JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
        event.put("Id", id);
        event.put("Time", time);
        event.put("File", file);
        event.put("Comment", comment);
        eventArr.put(event);
    }catch ( Exception e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

By the way, [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) preconize to name variables with a lowercase first letter, and classes with a uppercase first letter :)

Comment: Thanks!! it seems that was the mistake.... I hope the example can help other people

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line:

```
 EventArr.put(Event);
```

each time you invoke 'addEvent' your code updates object 'Event', and because of that at the end you see values added last. You should create new instance every time

```
public void addEvent(int Id, int Time, String File, String Comment) {
      try {
          Event = new JSONObject();
          Event.put("Id", Id);
          Event.put("Time", Time);
          Event.put("File", File);
          Event.put("Comment", Comment);
          EventArr.put(Event);
      }catch ( Exception e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```